# Incorrect JAR content since converting project to maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I am writing a [Bukkit](https://bukkit.org/pages/about-us/) plugin using Eclipse as my IDE; I had to use some code for which I had to use maven (I googled for javax.persistence and it seemed to be the only option, until later I figured out I could just add a javax persistence JAR to the project build path).

However, since I converted the project to the maven project the JAR contents looks like this:

```
com/
  example/
    main.class
META-INF/
src/
  plugin.yml
```

Whereas the JAR content previously was (the correct way):

```
com/
  example/
    main.class
META-INF/
plugin.yml
```

My project file structure looks like this:

[image]

I changed the project back to a normal project by clicking `disable maven nature` in `project -> right click menu -> configure` but the JAR output still is incorrect.

What do I need to change in order to fix this?

Comment: Are your java files located in `src/main/java`?

Comment: Please see the edited question, I included a picture that shows the file structure

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven uses some conventions to make our life easier.

One of them is that by default it looks up any java file always in the same folder inside a project: `src/main/java`.

Your java packages must be moved to this folder in order to be packed in the jar.

Take a look at [maven directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: they are packaged correctly, it's just the plugin.yml that for some odd reason gets separated in `<root>/src/` directory, whereas the other packages are  located properly in `<root>/com/oxidenetwork/etc..`

Comment: If you need a non-java file in yor package, put it in `src/main/resources`